# Games with hands, talking/chanting, rhythm, etc

Tags: vocabulary

I've played or observed a handful of games involving some sort of hand/rhythm/chanting component. Crucially they all have no equipment/items needed to play.

Examples:

- 가위바위보 "rock, paper, scissors"
- 토끼 토끼 토끼; 당근 당근 당근... (some rhythm and hand gestures accompanying this; you lose if you do the wrong one)

Is there a general term for these sorts of games? Are there any particularly well know examples? Are these games known to come from elsewhere, or do many originate in Korea?

Comment: Many games you can find with `술게임` literally means alcohol game. search it on Youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: There is no general term.

As Chase Choi said, many of the no-equipment games falls under the category of *sulgeim*, but it is not an exact match. *Kawibawibo*, for example, is not a *sulgeim*. Conversely, *sulgame* includes a few games where a sort of "equipment" is required, such as 병뚜껑치기.

The term itself is also problematic. Many "*sulgame*s" such as 아이엠 그라운드 is frequently played by minors, including elementary school students, with no alcohol involved.

I have no idea about their origination.